# How to calculate a value dependant on itself?

Tags: algorithms

I want to calculate a Profit Share Amount where the percentage is an expense and therefore affects the profit.

Let's assume:

```
Revenue 100,000
Expenses 50,000
Profit Share Percentage 50%
Profit Share Amount ?
```

Normally the Profit Share Amount would be equal to 25,000, however this would result in expenses rising from 50,000 to 75,000, which in turn lowers the Profit Share Amount to 12,500. This seems circular but there is a midpoint value where this equals out. In the above example it is 16,666.67. In other words this is 50% of profits when this amount is also an expense.

How can I calculate this value without using trial and error?

Answer (score 2):

Let us start with the equation:
$$
E = E_0 + P
$$
where $E$ are the expenses consisting of initial expenses $E_0$ plus the profit share amount $P$ then 
$$
P = (R - E) \frac{50}{100} = (R - (E_0 + P)) \frac{50}{100}
$$
where $R$ is the revenue.

Now you solve for $P$.

$$
\frac{100}{100} P = (R-E_0) \frac{50}{100} - \frac{50}{100} P \iff \\
\frac{150}{100} P = (R-E_0) \frac{50}{100} \iff \\
P = (R-E_0) \frac{50}{150} = \frac{1}{3}(R-E_0)
$$